# k8s rolling update algorithm

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

We have created our own custom resource a.k.a CRD and we need to add support for rolling update, as K8s is supporting it for deployments etc we want to reuse such logic, is there any lib which we can use (maybe partially) which we can use to support it? Or maybe learn and follow the logic as we don't want to re-invent the wheel? Any reference/lib would be helpful.

I've struggled to find this [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes).

Comment: ever heard of [operator sdk](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/)?

Comment: @LeiYang - yes of course,  we build the operator using kubebuilder. how it can help for rolling upgrade is there any lib /capability which we can use for that?

Comment: why do you think deployment is not sufficient, and you need crd be rolling upgraded? please give your example.

Comment: You're probably looking for the logic contained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/deployment/rolling.go#L32-L67). I'm not sure what your use-case is, but ideally your operator would just become an abstraction over a deployment and the deployment can manage the rolling upgrade for you. That might not work with your specific use-case, but if I were you, I'd try my best to use the existing deployment or replicaset functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted community wiki answer to summarise the problem.

[Clark McCauley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13906951/clark-mccauley) well suggested:

> You're probably looking for the logic contained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/deployment/rolling.go#L32-L67).

This is a reference to the k8s source code, so you probably won't find a better source of ideas :)

```
// rolloutRolling implements the logic for rolling a new replica set.
func (dc *DeploymentController) rolloutRolling(ctx context.Context, d *apps.Deployment, rsList []*apps.ReplicaSet) error {
    newRS, oldRSs, err := dc.getAllReplicaSetsAndSyncRevision(ctx, d, rsList, true)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    allRSs := append(oldRSs, newRS)

    // Scale up, if we can.
    scaledUp, err := dc.reconcileNewReplicaSet(ctx, allRSs, newRS, d)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if scaledUp {
        // Update DeploymentStatus
        return dc.syncRolloutStatus(ctx, allRSs, newRS, d)
    }

    // Scale down, if we can.
    scaledDown, err := dc.reconcileOldReplicaSets(ctx, allRSs, controller.FilterActiveReplicaSets(oldRSs), newRS, d)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if scaledDown {
        // Update DeploymentStatus
        return dc.syncRolloutStatus(ctx, allRSs, newRS, d)
    }

    if deploymentutil.DeploymentComplete(d, &d.Status) {
        if err := dc.cleanupDeployment(ctx, oldRSs, d); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    // Sync deployment status
    return dc.syncRolloutStatus(ctx, allRSs, newRS, d)
}
```